# Try/Except not working with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, exception, beautifulsoup, try-catch

I am trying to loop over a series of pages and extract some info. However, in certain pages some exceptions occur and I need to deal with them. I created the following function to try to deal with them. See below:

```
def iferr(x):
    try:
        x
    except (Exception, TypeError, AttributeError) as e:
        pass
```

I intend to use as part of code like this:

```
         articles = [[iferr(dp[0].find('span', class_='citation')),\
         iferr(dp[0].find('div', class_='abstract')),\
         iferr(dp[0].find('a', rel='nofollow')['href'])] for dp in data]
```

The idea is that if, for example, `dp[0].find('a', rel='nofollow')['href']` leads to an error (fails), it will simply ignore it (fill it with a blank or a None).

However, whenever an error/exception occurs in one of the three elements it does not 'pass'. It just tells me that the error has occurred. There errors it displays are those I listed in the 'except' command which I assume would be dealt with.

EDIT:

Per Michael's suggestion, I was able to see that the order in which iferr processes what is going on would always prompt the error before he try. So I worked on  workaround:

```
def fndwoerr(d,x,y,z,h):
try:
    if not h:
        d.find('x',y = 'z')
    else:
         d.find('x',y = 'z')['h']   
except (Exception, TypeError, AttributeError) as e:
    pass
...
articles = [[fndwoerr(dp[0],'span','class_','citation',None),\
        fndwoerr(dp[0],'div','class_','abstract',None),\
        fndwoerr(dp[0], 'a', 'rel','nofollow','href')] for dp in data]
```

Now it runs without prompting an error. However, everything returned becomes None. I am pretty sure it has to do with he way the parameters are entered. y should not be displayed as a string in the find function, whereas z has. However, I input both as string when i call the function. How can I go about this?

Comment: This can't work. The argument "x" to "iferr" is evaluated (or fails evaluation with an exception) before "iferr" is even called. "iferr" will never raise (and therefore not catch) such an exception.

Comment: Maybe the iferr approach is wrong, is there any other way in which i can bypass these exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

*Example looks a bit strange, so it would be a good idea to improve the question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. May read how to create [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)*

> The idea is that if, for example, dp[0].find('a',
> rel='nofollow')['href'] leads to an error (fails), it will simply
> ignore it (fill it with a blank or a None).

What about checking if element is available with an `if-statement`?

```
dp[0].find('a', rel='nofollow').get('href']) if dp[0].find('a', rel='nofollow') else None
```

or with `walrus operator` from `python 3.8`:

```
l.get('href']) if (l:=dp[0].find('a', rel='nofollow')) else None
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<h1>This is a Heading</h1>', 'html.parser')

for e in soup.select('h1'):
    print(e.find('a').get('href') if e.find('a') else None)
```